# How to Force Drop a Database that is in Emergency Mode and corrupt?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server 2014. We have a database that is in Emergency mode and is corrupt beyond repair. We need to get rid of it and reclaim the space. But we're having trouble as the database isn't even recognized, event though it is listed under Object Explorer.

We've tried straight forward DROP, but didn't work.

Tried this: `ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; DROP DATABASE DBNAME;` But didn't work.

Can't even Detach it.

What can we do here?

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE ... SET OFFLINE`. After that dropping should work, but it will not delete the database files -- you'll have to do that manually. (One of the problems with a totally corrupt DB is that the list of files may not even be correct, so the engine doesn't try.)

Comment: What errors are you getting?